# strlen() shows wrong character when trim the title wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding, char, strlen

strlen showing wrong character when at the end of the title is ë its showing "�..."

The is my code:

```
<?php $title = the_title('', '', false); 
$title = (strlen($title)<60) ? $title : substr($title,0,50)."...";
echo $title;
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unicode characters you need to use `mb_strlen()` and `mb_substr()`

Rewrite the above line to

```
$title = (mb_strlen($title,'utf-8')<60) ? $title : mb_substr($title,0,50,'utf-8')."...";
```

Comment: Iam getting this error: Warning: strlen() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/oranews/public_html/wp-content/themes/oranews/loop-single.php on line 44

Comment: I said `mb_strlen()` why are you still using `strlen()` ?

Comment: Iam installing mbstring on my server i hope this will help :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues after that.